# Is $[1,2]\times \Bbb R$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $[1,2]\times \Bbb R$ closed in $\Bbb R^2$? The answer is no. But I suggest it is yes, since it contains all its boundary points right? Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Can you prove its complement is open i.e.$\{(-\infty,1)\times\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(2,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\}$ is open?

Comment: You are right. answer is wrong. Of course it isn't *compact* in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: yes, $[1,2]\times\Bbb R$ is closed in the euclidean topology

Comment: @coffeemath: Compactness is not relevant here I guess.

Comment: @YadatiKiran You're right-- just threw that in in case OP wondered about that, or in case the wording of the question was diferent. [seems odd that the "answer" would be wrong about such a simple question. wonder what book said that..]

Comment: @coffeemath:  Smart ! Its complement is open so may be the book is wrong.

Comment: Shara-- what book said that answer? [just curious]

Comment: It depends on the metric and/or topology but if we assume the euclidean metric it's closed for *all*  the arguments you would consider to be reasonable.  There really is no catch or trick.  Can you tell us why the book said it was closed? It's possibly they made a typo or that you misread but you, and everyone else so far, have been correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a sequence $(x_n)$ of points in $[1,2]\times \mathbb{R}$. If we write $x_n=(y_n,z_n)$ in the coordinates on the product space then we  see that if the sequence $x_n$  converges, then so do the  sequences $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ in $[1,2]$ and $\mathbb{R}$, respectively. Now, $[1,2]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are closed so that $y_n\to y\in [1,2]$ and $z_n\to z\in \mathbb{R}$. So, $x_n\to x=(y,z)\in [1,2]\times \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, $[1,2]\times \mathbb{R}$  is closed.

Remark: As mentioned in the comments: $[1,2]\times \mathbb{R}$ is not compact because it is not bounded. The Heine-Borel Theorem says that in the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: Antonius.Nice answer +.